# Unnumbered Part in classicthesis changes font of TOC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am trying to have a part without the part number. Initially my solution was to use 
    `\part*{Overture}`
instead of 
    `\part{Overture}`
Which works fine in the main text

The problem is that the font  of this entry is changed in the TOC. So, how can I have an unnumbered chapter without ruining the format of the TOC?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright, titlepage, fleqn, headinclude, footinclude, BCOR5mm, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty, captions=tableheading]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[parts, linedheaders, pdfspacing, eulermath, beramono, eulerchapternumbers, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
  \begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\part*{Overture}
 \part{Dislocations} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, why are there multiple `u2029` in your example?

Comment: btw: starred parts usually don't go to the TOC. Seems like this is a bug within `classicthesis`.

Comment: @Johannes_B. I am not sure what you mean with     u2029. And I agree with you that it seems to be a bug in      classicthesis

Comment: There are unicode pragraph separators in your code, probably caused by copy and paste. Please copy your example from above and test it out. If they are in your original document, this will lead to errors and you should be aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the `\part*` command doesn't accept short and long title, like `\part[short title]{long title}` does. Classicthesis alters the short title in the `\part` command to have it typeset in `spacedlowsmallcaps` in the table of contents.
 A workaround would be to use `\part*{\hspace{1em} \textls[80]{\scshape{overture}}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As starred parts do not make a toc entry, they don't have an optional argument. `\addpart` (provided by KOMA) does and also provides a toc entry. `\addpart*` makes unnumbered parts more robust. The whole implementation of parts in `classicthesis` is faulty.