# Remove Part from TOC (Classicthesis)

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis, parts

I want to have a Part that is not numbered and that does not show up in the TOC. Usually, I would use the command `\part*{Intro}` instead of `\part{Intro}`, but with the package `classicthesis` this does not work.

The problem is that the Part (Intro) is still appearing in the TOC, and it also appears with a different font.

Any Ideas how to remove the entry from the TOC? Or, at least, how to make it appear with the correct font?

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright, titlepage, fleqn,%
 headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
 numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty,%
 captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

 \usepackage[parts, linedheaders, pdfspacing, eulermath, %
 beramono, eulerchapternumbers, dottedtoc] {classicthesis}
 \usepackage{arsclassica}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \part*{Intro}
 \part{Part 1}
 \part{Part 2}
 \part{Part 3}
 \part{Part 4}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: As i said iin [Unnumbered Part in classicthesis changes font of TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210793) this is a bug due to false implementation. This should be fixed by the author of `classicthesis`.

Comment: @Johannes_B. I agree. But in the meantime I need to find an alternative solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `classicthesic.sty` somehow does not provide `\part{}` i.e. `\Part{}` with just one mandatory argument, thereby confusing `\part*{}` somewhat. 
It's another 'proof' of the somewhat strange behaviour of `classicthesis`.

A little hack can cure this, but I am not sure if this is the desired behaviour.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright, titlepage, fleqn,%
 headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
 numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty,%
 captions=tableheading]{scrbook}


\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part

\usepackage[parts, linedheaders, pdfspacing, eulermath, %
beramono, eulerchapternumbers, dottedtoc] {classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\makeatletter

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}%
{% 
  \newcommand{\UnstarredPart@@NoOpt}[1]{%
    \UnstarredPart@@Opt[#1]{#1}%
  }%

  \newcommand{\UnstarredPart}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\UnstarredPart@@Opt}{\UnstarredPart@@NoOpt}%
  }%

  \renewcommand*{\part}{%
    \@ifstar{\StarredPart}{\UnstarredPart}%
  }%

  \global\newcommand{\UnstarredPart@@Opt}[2][]{%
    \ifpdf\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart}%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}]{#2}% spacedallcaps spacedlowsmallcaps
    \else%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}]{#2}%
    \fi%
    % \renewcommand{\ct@parttext}{\relax}% Thanks to Ivo!
    \ctparttext{\relax}%
  }%
  \global\newcommand{\StarredPart}[1]{\LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}}%
  \ifxetex% 
  \renewcommand\UnstarredPart@@Opt[2][]{%
    \ifxetex\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart}%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}]{#2}% spacedallcaps spacedlowsmallcaps
                 \else%
                 \LaTeXStandardPart[\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}]{#2}%
                 \fi%
                 \ctparttext{\relax}%
           }%
               \fi%

}{\relax}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part*{Intro}
\part{Part 1}
\part{Part 2}
\part{Part 3}
\part{Part 4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You managed to remove the part from the TOC. But now the font of all the part titles  has changed in the document

Comment: @Sebas_n1: I will have a look tomorrow, but note, as Johannes_B stated: `classicthesis` is not well-designed and it should not used actually